# sequelize - bulk insert on duplicate update

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have following schema,

```
create table test (id int primary key ,x integer)
```

And I want to update **column x** on duplicate with **old + new value**

like following raw query with sequelize-nodejs.

```
INSERT INTO test (id,x) VALUES (1,5)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE x=x+VALUES(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

> **Step 1** : find instance
>   **Step 2** : update the value with old + new

and

> **Step 3** : save the instance

```
Table.find({
          where: { //condition }
        })
        .then(entity => {
          if (entity) {
            entity.val += req.body.newVal;
            return entity.save()
              .then(() => {
                res.status(200);
              })
              .catch(validationError(res));
          } else {
            return res.status(404).end();
          }
        })
```